# Problems inserting data into a database from a parsed array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

```
-(void)saveTheData:(InternetResource*)_resource
{
    currentResultsList= [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[iconnect.responseString JSONValue]] mutableCopy];
    //NSLog(@"Response String:  %@",iconnect.responseString);
    NSLog(@"bla bla%@",currentResultsList);
    NSString *databaseName = @"olympics_db3";//rodeo_database_details //rodeo_user_database
    NSLog(@"dsdsd %@",databaseName);
    NSString *path =[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
}

sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
const char *dbpath = [path UTF8String];


if (sqlite3_open(dbpath,&sql) == SQLITE_OK)
{  
    NSInteger athleteID;
    NSInteger countryMedal;
    NSInteger eventID;
    NSString *result;
    NSInteger resultID;
    NSInteger sportID;
    NSInteger typeOfMedal;

    for(int i=0;i<[currentResultsList count];i++)
    {
        if ([[currentResultsList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"athleteID"]==(id)[NSNull null] || [[[currentResultsList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"athleteID"] length]==0)
        {
            athleteID=0;    

        }
        else
        {
             athleteID=[[[currentResultsList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"athleteID"] integerValue];
        }
        if ([[currentResultsList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"countryMedal"]==(id)[NSNull null] || [[[currentResultsList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"countryMedal"] length]==0)
        {
            countryMedal=0;
        }
        else
        {
            countryMedal=[[[currentResultsList objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"countryMedal"]integerValue];
        }
        if ([[currentResultsList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"eventID"]==(id)[NSNull null] || [[[currentResultsList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"eventID"] length]==0)
        {
            eventID=0;
        }
        else
        {
        eventID= [[[currentResultsList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"eventID"]integerValue];
        }
        if ([[currentResultsList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"result"]==(id)[NSNull null] || [[[currentResultsList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"result"] length]==0)
        {
            result=@"";
        }
        else{
        result= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[currentResultsList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"result"]];
        }
        if ([[currentResultsList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"resultID"]==(id)[NSNull null] || [[[currentResultsList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"resultID"] length]==0)
        {
            resultID=0;
        }
        else
        {
        resultID= [[[currentResultsList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"resultID"]integerValue];
        }
        if ([[currentResultsList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sportID"]==(id)[NSNull null] || [[[currentResultsList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sportID"] length]==0)
        {
            sportID=0;
        }
        else
        {
        sportID= [[[currentResultsList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sportID"]integerValue];
        }
        if ([[currentResultsList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"typeOfMedal"]==(id)[NSNull null] || [[[currentResultsList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"typeOfMedal"] length]==0)
        {
            typeOfMedal=0;
        }
        else{
        typeOfMedal=[[[currentResultsList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"typeOfMedal"]integerValue];
        }
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO Result (`athleteID`,`countryMedal`,`eventID`,`result`,`resultID`,`sportID`,`typeOfMedal`) VALUES ('%d','%d', '%d','%@','%d','%d','%d')",athleteID,countryMedal,eventID,result,resultID,sportID,typeOfMedal];
        NSLog(@"InsertQery: %@", insertSQL);

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(sql, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"Data Inserted");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Data Inserted failed");        
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(sql);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What error message are you getting, what have you tried to fix it, crucial information. We cant read your mind.

Comment: its not seeing any error.but data is not inserted in database.I am in a huge drag man.please let me out of this :

Comment: Unfortunately im unfamiliar with sqlite, but just looking at your save code it doesn't look like you actually commit an changes to your DB, in fact I dont even see where you call that function. You seem to have plenty of printouts, are all of your SQL statements set correctly, none of your values are null, etc?

Comment: everything is ok.i am getting the output of my query too.bt after getting the result,there is a condition as u see up in the code.this condition is not working.bt i dont get the reason behind its not working.

Comment: try using isEqual, I'm not sure it applies but I know you cannot use  "==" in certain situations such as when comparing strings, so that may help. And youre sure that sqlite3_step(statement) should be equal to SQLITE_DONE? Have you verified that it actually is in the debugger?